# How do I generate a static copy of my github project wiki?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki, gollum-wiki

I'd like to generate a local static copy of the generated HTML of my github project wiki, from the directory of markdown files.

What's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

nowadays, it works with :

```
require 'gollum-lib'
wiki = Gollum::Wiki.new("/mywikirepo")
wiki.pages.each{|p| puts p.formatted_data }
```

Answer (score 0):

- clone your repository locally and grab the wiki submodule (see [here](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis))
- install the `gollum` and `redcarpet` gems
- ruby:

  ```
  require 'gollum'
  wiki = Gollum::Wiki.new("proj.wiki")
  wiki.pages.each{|p| puts p.formatted_data }
  ```