# Are there any static site generators that can publish github wikis?

Tags: github, wiki, github-flavored-markdown, static-site

We have a number of wikis associated with private repositories on github. The developers have access to them via per-user-pricing but we want to give others in the business read-only access to the wiki content, without paying for extra seats or requiring a github login.

I'd like to find a way of publishing the markdown based wiki pages to a simple static site (one per wiki is fine) which can then be deployed to Azure, with appropriate access controls using Azure Active Directory.

I've found this but don't understand it and would prefer a .NET and/or JavaScript solution: [How do I generate a static copy of my github project wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675945/how-do-i-generate-a-static-copy-of-my-github-project-wiki)

Comment: To the people that have voted this as "off-topic because...", please tell me where you'd prefer I post it.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/deploying-your-docs/
You can use it to deploy the docs.

Also check this: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/

Comment: MkDocs looks good, I'd prefer it if there was no Python dependency though.